# Ajuda em bloco anonimo com IF em PL/SQL

Tags: pl-sql

Estou estudando PL/SQL por conta propria e ando tendo muita dificuldade, gostaria de dicar de como posso melhorar o codigo abaixo. Estou usando a logica de querer puxar e contar todas as vezes que aparece a letra "M" na tabela abaixo. Só que esta dando erro na parte do Else, se alguem tiver alguma dica também como melhorar o codigo, ou qual a melhor maneira de fazer isto.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
`declare 
 contador NUMBER;
 contador2 NUMBER;
begin
SELECT SEX FROM EMPLOYEE;
contador := 0;
contador2 := 0;
 if EMPLOYEE.SEX = 'M'  
   then loop 
       contador := contador + 1;
      else 
      contador := contador2 + 1;
   end if;
   end loop;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Numero de sexo Masculino é', contador, 
   'Numero de sexo feminino é', contador2);
end`
```

Comment: não programo em pl/sql, porém, vendo a documentação, a estrutura do IF não parece ter esse `loop`.

Comment: o loop realmente nao faz parte, mas é permitido pelo pl/sql colocar estruturar em loop dentro de IF's e Else, nesse caso eu utilizei pois estou incrementando os contadores para saber quantas vezes aparece M ou F dentro da coluna

Comment: talvez na linha `contador := contador2 + 1` não deveria ser `contador2 := contador2 + 1`?

Comment: Creio que você está equivocadamente considerando que seu loop irá percorrer as linhas resultantes do select. Veja cursor ou, melhor ainda, utilize uma função de agregação no select.

Comment: eu consegui resolver aqui com FOR com a ajuda de um pessoal da minha empresa, vou postar o codigo

Comment: mas valeu dms pela ajuda e pelas dicas

Answer (score 0):

```
    declare 
 contador NUMBER := 0;
 contador2 NUMBER := 0;
begin
 for REG in(Select * FROM EMPLOYEE)LOOP 
  if REG.SEX = 'M' then
  contador := contador + 1;
  else
  contador2 := contador2 + 1;
  end if;
  end LOOP;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Masculino: 'contador' Feminino: ' contador2); 

end;
```

Na maneira acima resolvi com o FOR e na de baixo foi oque me orientaram fazendo com apenas um SELECT.

```
SELECT SEX, COUNT(1) FROM EMPLOYEED GROUP BY SEX;
```